# Multiline equations with one identifier

Tags: equations

I have a two line equation, but the following code puts two numbers (e.g. (1) and (2))

```
\begin{alignat}{2}
   &E_{peer} = E_{miss} \\
                    &+ h_{3} \times (E_{dir}+E_{r}+E_{L2}(access)+h_{4} \times E_{wire}) 
\end{alignat}
```

The output is

[image]

However there should be only one number.

Comment: Use `\begin{align}\begin{aligned}`

Comment: You mean I have remove `\begin{alignat}{2}`? But I want to align left the equations

Comment: Yes. Also, use `E_{\text{peer}}`

Comment: `\begin{align}\begin{aligned}...\end{align}\end{aligned}` has error and says LaTeX Error: \begin{align} on input line 70 ended by \end{aligned}.

Comment: @Sigur -- better to use `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} ... \end{aligned}\end{equation}`

Comment: You are closing wrong nested. From inside to outside.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Oh, yes, of course. Well noticed. Thanks.

Comment: you can put `\nonumber` before the `\\ `

Comment: As @barbarabeeton noticed, use `\begin{equation}\begin{aligned} & E_{peer}  = E_{miss} \\  & .... `

Comment: @David Carlisle: Yes it is much easier. Thanks

Comment: @mahmood, note that using `\nonumber` the number will be at the same line not vertical centered.

Comment: unrelated to the numbering but never use math italic for multi-letter identifiers such as `access` or `wire` the font is designed to make them _not_ look like a word but as a product of separate variables. use `\mathit{access}`   `\mathit{wire}` etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prepared three variants. Choose which one you like best (I recommend the first one with `multline`).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some text
\begin{multline}
  E_{peer} = E_{miss} \\
  + h_{3} \times (E_{dir}+E_{r}+E_{L2}(access)+h_{4} \times E_{wire}) 
\end{multline}
Some text
\begin{equation}
  \begin{split}    
    &E_{peer} = E_{miss} \\
    &+ h_{3} \times (E_{dir}+E_{r}+E_{L2}(access)+h_{4} \times E_{wire}) 
  \end{split}
\end{equation}
Some text
\begin{align}
    &E_{peer} = E_{miss}\notag\\
    &+ h_{3} \times (E_{dir}+E_{r}+E_{L2}(access)+h_{4} \times E_{wire}) 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## Enhanced Typography

It is good practice to set indices with more than one letter and word in an upright shape. I also like to use another set of delimiters for the outer level and make those a little larger, because small parentheses were already used to delimit the argument of a function (if brackets conflict with other notation, e.g. the commutator in quantum mechanics you should reconsider).

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\noindent Some text
\begin{multline}
  E_{\mathrm{peer}} = E_{\mathrm{miss}} \\
  + h_{3} \times \bigl[E_{\mathrm{dir}}+E_{r}+E_{L2}(\mathrm{access})+h_{4} \times E_{\mathrm{wire}}\bigr] 
\end{multline}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: but see comment on the question about `\mathit` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I would never typeset words in math italic but maybe OP want's it that way. Also if I wanted to show enhanced typography I would have posted only the `multline` solution.

Comment: Henri yes showing the differentlayouts is nice (I'd already voted:-) and I wasn't suggesting you change the answer, I just didn't want people coming in and copying the accepted answer without noticing comments on the question....

Comment: @DavidCarlisle See my updated answer :-)